# tf.contrib.data.Dataset seems does not support SparseTensor

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I generated a pascal voc 2007 tfrecords file using the code in tensorflow object detection API. I use [`tf.contrib.data.Dataset` API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset) to read data from tfrecords. I tried mehtod without `tf.contrib.data.Dataset` API, and the code can run without any error, but when changed to `tf.contrib.data.Dataset` API it can not work correctly.

The code without `tf.contrib.data.Dataset`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    slim_example_decoder = tf.contrib.slim.tfexample_decoder

    features = {"image/height": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=1),
                "image/width": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=1),
                "image/filename": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
                "image/source_id": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
                "image/key/sha256": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
                "image/encoded": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
                "image/format": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value="jpeg"),
                "image/object/bbox/xmin": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
                "image/object/bbox/xmax": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
                "image/object/bbox/ymin": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
                "image/object/bbox/ymax": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
                "image/object/class/text": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
                "image/object/class/label": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
                "image/object/difficult": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
                "image/object/truncated": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
                "image/object/view": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64)}
    items_to_handlers = {
        'image': slim_example_decoder.Image(
            image_key='image/encoded', format_key='image/format', channels=3),
        'source_id': (
            slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/source_id')),
        'key': (
            slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/key/sha256')),
        'filename': (
            slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/filename')),
        # Object boxes and classes.
        'groundtruth_boxes': (
            slim_example_decoder.BoundingBox(
                ['ymin', 'xmin', 'ymax', 'xmax'], 'image/object/bbox/')),
        'groundtruth_classes': (
            slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/object/class/label')),
        'groundtruth_difficult': (
            slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/object/difficult')),
        'image/object/truncated': (
            slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/object/truncated')),
        'image/object/view': (
            slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/object/view')),
    }
    decoder = slim_example_decoder.TFExampleDecoder(features, items_to_handlers)
    keys = decoder.list_items()
    for example in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(
          "/home/aurora/workspaces/data/tfrecords_data/oxford_pet/pet_train.record"):
        serialized_example = tf.reshape(example, shape=[])
        tensors = decoder.decode(serialized_example, items=keys)
        tensor_dict = dict(zip(keys, tensors))
        tensor_dict['image'].set_shape([None, None, 3])
        print(tensor_dict)
```

the output of above code is :

```py
{'image': <tf.Tensor 'case/If_1/Merge:0' shape=(?, ?, 3) dtype=uint8>,
 'filename': <tf.Tensor 'Reshape_2:0' shape=() dtype=string>,
 'groundtruth_boxes': <tf.Tensor 'transpose:0' shape=(?, 4) dtype=float32>,
 'key': <tf.Tensor 'Reshape_5:0' shape=() dtype=string>,
 'image/object/truncated': <tf.Tensor 'SparseToDense:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>,
 'groundtruth_classes': <tf.Tensor 'SparseToDense_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>,
 'image/object/view': <tf.Tensor 'SparseToDense_1:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>,
 'source_id': <tf.Tensor 'Reshape_6:0' shape=() dtype=string>,
 'groundtruth_difficult': <tf.Tensor 'SparseToDense_3:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>}
...
```

Code with `tf.contrib.data.Dataset`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.data import Iterator

slim_example_decoder = tf.contrib.slim.tfexample_decoder

flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('data_dir',
  '/home/aurora/workspaces/data/tfrecords_data/voc_dataset/trainval.tfrecords',
  'tfrecords file output path')
flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 32, 'training batch size')
flags.DEFINE_integer('capacity', 10000, 'training batch size')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

features = {"image/height": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=1),
        "image/width": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=1),
        "image/filename": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
        "image/source_id": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
        "image/key/sha256": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
        "image/encoded": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
        "image/format": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value="jpeg"),
        "image/object/bbox/xmin": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        "image/object/bbox/xmax": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        "image/object/bbox/ymin": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        "image/object/bbox/ymax": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        "image/object/class/text": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
        "image/object/class/label": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
        "image/object/difficult": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
        "image/object/truncated": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
        "image/object/view": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64)
      }

items_to_handlers = {
    'image': slim_example_decoder.Image(
        image_key='image/encoded', format_key='image/format', channels=3),
    'source_id': (
        slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/source_id')),
    'key': (
        slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/key/sha256')),
    'filename': (
        slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/filename')),
    # Object boxes and classes.
    'groundtruth_boxes': (
        slim_example_decoder.BoundingBox(
            ['ymin', 'xmin', 'ymax', 'xmax'], 'image/object/bbox/')),
    'groundtruth_classes': (
        slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/object/class/label')),
    'groundtruth_difficult': (
        slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/object/difficult')),
    'image/object/truncated': (
        slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/object/truncated')),
    'image/object/view': (
        slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/object/view')),
    }
decoder = slim_example_decoder.TFExampleDecoder(features, items_to_handlers)
keys = decoder.list_items()


def _parse_function_train(example):
  serialized_example = tf.reshape(example, shape=[])
  tensors = decoder.decode(serialized_example, items=keys)
  tensor_dict = dict(zip(keys, tensors))
  tensor_dict['image'].set_shape([None, None, 3])
  print(tensor_dict)
  return tensor_dict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(FLAGS.data_dir)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.map(_parse_function_train)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat(1)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=FLAGS.capacity)
    iterator = Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types,
                                   train_dataset.output_shapes)
    next_element = iterator.get_next()
    training_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(train_dataset)

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(training_init_op)
    counter = 0
    while True:
        try:
            sess.run(next_element)
            counter += 1
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('End of training data in step %d' %counter)
            break
```

When run the above code, it report the following errors:

```py
2017-10-09 23:41:43.488439: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192]     Invalid argument: Name: <unknown>, Key: image/object/view, Index: 0.  Data types don't match. Expected type: int64
2017-10-09 23:41:43.488554: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Name: <unknown>, Key: image/object/view, Index: 0.  Data types don't match. Expected type: int64
 [[Node: ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=7, Nsparse=9, Tdense=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_INT64], dense_shapes=[[], [], [], [], [], [], []], sparse_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT64]](ParseSingleExample/ExpandDims, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/names, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_0, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_1, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_2, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_3, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_4, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_5, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_6, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_7, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_8, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_1, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_2, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_3, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_4, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_5, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_6, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_1, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_2, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_3, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_4, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_5, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_6)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1327, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1306, in _run_fn
status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Name: <unknown>, Key: image/object/view, Index: 0.  Data types don't match. Expected type: int64
 [[Node: ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=7, Nsparse=9, Tdense=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_INT64], dense_shapes=[[], [], [], [], [], [], []], sparse_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT64]](ParseSingleExample/ExpandDims, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/names, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_0, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_1, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_2, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_3, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_4, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_5, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_6, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_7, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_8, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_1, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_2, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_3, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_4, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_5, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_6, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_1, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_2, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_3, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_4, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_5, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_6)]]
 [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?], [?,?,4], [?,?], [?,?], [?,?,?,3], [?,?], [?,?], [?], [?]], output_types=[DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_UINT8, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_STRING], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Iterator)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aurora/workspaces/PycharmProjects/object_detection_models/datasets/voc_dataset/voc_tfrecords_decode_test.py", line 83, in <module>
sess.run(next_element)
  File "/usr/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Name: <unknown>, Key: image/object/view, Index: 0.  Data types don't match. Expected type: int64
 [[Node: ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=7, Nsparse=9, Tdense=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_INT64], dense_shapes=[[], [], [], [], [], [], []], sparse_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT64]](ParseSingleExample/ExpandDims, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/names, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_0, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_1, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_2, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_3, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_4, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_5, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_6, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_7, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_8, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_1, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_2, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_3, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_4, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_5, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_6, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_1, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_2, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_3, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_4, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_5, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/Reshape_6)]]
 [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?], [?,?,4], [?,?], [?,?], [?,?,?,3], [?,?], [?,?], [?], [?]], output_types=[DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_UINT8, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_STRING], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Iterator)]]
```

The code to generate tfrecords file can reference [create_pascal_tf_record.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/create_pascal_tf_record.py).

Comment: I have solved this problems. The `tf.contrib.data.Dataset` can read voc tfrecords, but the batch size can only be set to 1.  Please reference this page [tf_contrib_data_Dataset_voc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682855/tf-contrib-data-dataset-batch-size-can-only-set-to-1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT (2018/01/25):** `tf.SparseTensor` support was added to `tf.data` in TensorFlow 1.5. The code in the question should work in TensorFlow 1.5 or later.

---

Up to TF 1.4, the `tf.contrib.data` API did not support `tf.SparseTensor` objects in dataset elements. There are a couple of workarounds:

1. **(Harder, but probably faster.)** If a `tf.SparseTensor` object `st` represents a variable-length list of features, you may be able to return `st.values` instead of `st` from the `map()` function. Note that you would probably then need to pad the results using [`Dataset.padded_batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch) instead of [`Dataset.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch).
2. **(Easier, but probably slower.)** In the `_parse_function_train()` function, iterate over `tensor_dict` and produce a new version where any `tf.SparseTensor` objects have been converted to a `tf.Tensor` using [`tf.serialize_sparse()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/serialize_sparse). When you

   ```
   # NOTE: You could probably infer these from `keys`.
   sparse_keys = set()

   def _parse_function_train(example):
     serialized_example = tf.reshape(example, shape=[])
     tensors = decoder.decode(serialized_example, items=keys)
     tensor_dict = dict(zip(keys, tensors))
     tensor_dict['image'].set_shape([None, None, 3])

     rewritten_tensor_dict = {}
     for key, value in tensor_dict.items():
       if isinstance(value, tf.SparseTensor):
         rewritten_tensor_dict[key] = tf.serialize_sparse(value)
         sparse_keys.add(key)
       else:
         rewritten_tensor_dict[key] = value
     return rewritten_tensor_dict
   ```

   Then, after you get the `next_element` dictionary from `iterator.get_next()`, you can reverse this conversion using [`tf.deserialize_many_sparse()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/deserialize_many_sparse):

   ```
   next_element = iterator.get_next()

   for key in sparse_keys:
     next_element[key] = tf.deserialize_many_sparse(key)
   ```

Comment: Hi @mrry, How to write a tf.SparseTensor to an example? Can we avoid sess.run() or .eval() during this process? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [`tf.SparseTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor), there is [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd)  that seems to achieve the same result except you may have to recover the indices later.

These two code blocks achieves same result

```
indices = tf.concat([xy_indices, z_indices], axis=-1)
values  = tf.concat([bboxes, objectness, one_hot], axis=1)

SparseTensor = tf.SparseTensor(indices= indices,
                               values = values, 
                               dense_shape =[output_size, output_size,
                                            len(anchors), 4 + 1 + num_classes])

DenseTensor = tf.scatter_nd(indices = indices,
                            updates = values
                            shape   = [output_size, output_size,
                                       len(anchors),4 + 1 + num_classes])
```