# Tensorflow Dataset with different shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use convolutional network for clasifying images with different shapes. I can not find a way to load images in Tensorflow. Based on [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2354) it should work with tf.data.Dataset(). I create Dataset in this manner:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(read_file)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(samples_in_buffer)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
```

When executed I am getting this error

```
HandleElementToSlice Cannot copy slice: number of elements does not match.  Shapes are: [element]: [295,256,3], [parent slice]: [276,128,3]
```

Is it possible to load images with different sizes, shuffle and batch them using Tensorflow?

Remark: I want to use Spatial pyramid pooling to handle different image sizes.

Answer (score 7):

dataset.batch() is trying to build a dense batch from tensors of different sizes (your different sized images), as mentioned here: [tf.contrib.data.DataSet batch size can only set to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682855/tf-contrib-data-dataset-batch-size-can-only-set-to-1)

Your code is likely to work if either 1. you are setting batch_size = 1 or 2. resize all images to same size, e.g. using tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad() in your read_file-function.

Another option would be to use dataset.padded_batch(...) instead of dataset.batch and specify the padded_shape such that all images have the same size (incl. padding), i.e. probably dataset.padded_batch(batch_size, padded_shape=[None]).

Lastly, in the upcoming TF r1.4 you might use dataset.from_generator().