# Tensorflow dataset with vectors of differing shapes

Tags: tensorflow, vector, dataset, shapes, tensor

I am trying to create a dataset from vectors which can have differing lengths (the data column). I am currently using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
shapes = [[3,2],[2,2]]
classes = [0,1]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
   {"data": tf.constant(data),
    "shape": tf.constant(shapes),
    "class": tf.constant(classes)})

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = sess.run(dataset)
    print(x)
```

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    {"data": tf.constant(data),
  File "/Users/[username]/Documents/University/Project/Application/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 214, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/Users/[username]/Documents/University/Project/Application/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 442, in make_tensor_proto
    _GetDenseDimensions(values)))
ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]] - got shape [2], but wanted [2, 6].
```

What is the correct method to set up a dataset which can accept vectors of different lengths? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46791765/tensorflow-dataset-with-different-shapes) question addresses the issue when reading from a file, however, I am defining the data explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either pad the tensors yourself or you use sparse tensors.

I usually use sparse tensors. When you convert the sparse tensors to dense you can specify what the size should be and have the padding done for you.

The usual case for such tensors are either input strings, bags of words or sequences. The embedding operations handle strings and bags of words. The sequences are usually handled with rnn related operations (check out [tf.nn.static_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_rnn) for example)

In general you want the tensors to eventually have the same length in the same batch because the matrix operations need to have matrix operands.

Comment: If I were to use Dataset.padded_batch() to pad later on, how would I first create the sparse tensors?