# Parsing tfrecords with tf.feature_column.make_parse_spec and tf.contrib.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I have created a simple tfrecords file using the following code.

```
data_rows = [
    ("Male", "White", 12332.0),
    ("Female", "Black", 232324.0),
    ("Female", "Other", 12313.0)
]


def float_feature(x):
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[float(x)]))


def string_feature(x):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[x.strip().encode("ascii")]))

tfrecords_path = "simple.tfrecords"

with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecords_path) as writer:
    for gender, race, earnings in data_rows:
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
            "gender": string_feature(gender),
            "race": string_feature(race),
            "earnings": float_feature(earnings)
        }))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

Now I want to create a tf.contrib.data.Dataset from this using the tf.feature_column feature columns. I have defined my features like this.

```
gender = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list("gender", ["Female", "Male"])
race = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list("race", ["White", "Black", "Other"])
earnings = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("earnings")
parse_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec([gender, race, earnings])
```

I'm then trying to use the following code to apply a parse function to each row of the raw tfrecords dataset using the features I defined above.

```
raw_dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecords_path)

def parse_example(example):
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example, parse_spec)
    return parsed_features

dataset = raw_dataset.map(parse_example)
```

This breaks with the following stack trace.

```
<TFRecordDataset shapes: (), types: tf.string>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 460, in make_tensor_proto
    str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
  File "/home/john/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 460, in <listcomp>
    str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
  File "/home/john/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 65, in as_bytes
    (bytes_or_text,))
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7f49714edf98>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simpletfrecords.py", line 87, in <module>
    parse_with_dataset()
  File "simpletfrecords.py", line 53, in parse_with_dataset
    dataset = raw_dataset.map(parse_example)
  File "/home/john/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 964, in map
    return MapDataset(self, map_func, num_threads, output_buffer_size)
  File "/home/john/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1735, in __init__
    self._map_func.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())
  File "/home/john/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 449, in add_to_graph
    self._create_definition_if_needed()
  File "/home/john/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/framework/function.py", line 168, in _create_definition_if_needed
    outputs = self._func(*inputs)
  File "/home/john/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1726, in tf_map_func
    flattened_ret = [ops.convert_to_tensor(t) for t in nest.flatten(ret)]
  File "/home/john/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1726, in <listcomp>
    flattened_ret = [ops.convert_to_tensor(t) for t in nest.flatten(ret)]
  File "/home/john/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 611, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/home/john/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 676, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/home/john/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 121, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/home/john/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 102, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/home/john/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 464, in make_tensor_proto
    "supported type." % (type(values), values))
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("ParseSingleExample/Slice_Indices_gender:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample:2", shape=(?,), dtype=string), dense_shape=Tensor("ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_Shape_gender:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

So the parse function expects a byte string to read the features from but it seems like it's already a SparseTensor for some reason that I don't understand.

I then tried parsing the same tfrecords file using the "old" way with queues.

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([tfrecords_path], num_epochs=1)
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
features_op = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, parse_spec)
...
sess.run((tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()))
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

features = sess.run(features_op)
```

Which gives me this output so it seems to work I guess. But my question is, how do I make this work with tf.contrib.data.Dataset?

```
{'gender': SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[0]]), values=array([b'Male'], dtype=object), dense_shape=array([1])), 'race': SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[0]]), values=array([b'White'], dtype=object), dense_shape=array([1])), 'earnings': array([ 12332.], dtype=float32)}
```

TLDR: I want to use tf.feature_column to define my features and then create input functions reading from tfrecord files that are compatible with the tf.estimator classes. Preferably I want to use the tf.contrib.data.Dataset API for this.

Comment: I think the issue is that tf.feature_column.make_parse_spec makes a parse spec suitable for tf.parse_example and not tf.parse_single_example in which case I wonder how I can make it work with the mapping function in dataset which seems to be applied to each row.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46732695/3574081). TL;DR the `Dataset` transformations do not currently support `tf.SparseTensor`, so the answer has a couple of workarounds for the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a rough ETA on when this will be supported?

Comment: Not yet, but I've created a GitHub issue that you can follow to see when support turns up in the master branch: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13766