# Write and Read SparseTensor to and from a tfrecord file

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix, tfrecord

Is it possible to do this elegantly?

Right now only thing I can think of is to save the indices (tf.int64), values (tf.float32), and shape (tf.int64) of the SparseTensor in 3 separate Features (the first two are VarLenFeature and the last one is FixedLenFeature). This seems really cumbersome.

Any advise is appreciated!

## Update 1

My answer below is not suitable for building a computation graph (b/c the contents of the sparse tensor have to be extracted via sess.run(), which costs a lot of time if called repeatedly.)

Inspired by [mrry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46732695/8179854), I think maybe we can get the bytes generated by `tf.serialize_sparse` so later we can recover the SparseTensor using `tf.deserialize_many_sparse`. But `tf.serialize_sparse` is not implemented in pure python (it calls the external function `SerializeSparse`), which means we still need to use `sess.run()` to get the bytes. How can I get a pure python version of `SerializeSparse`? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this problem of writing and reading sparse tensors to and from a TFRecord file, and I have found very little information about this online.

One solution, as you propose, is to store the indices, values, and shape of the SparseTensor in 3 separate Features, which is discussed [here](https://planspace.org/20170427-sparse_tensors_and_tfrecords/). This does not seem efficient or elegant.

I've got a working example (with `TensorFlow 2.0.0.alpha0`).
Maybe not the most elegant, but it seems to work.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Example data
st_1 = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0,0],[1,2]], values=[1,2], dense_shape=[3,4])
st_2 = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0,1],[2,0],[3,3]], values=[3,9,5], dense_shape=[4, 4])
sparse_tensors = [st_1, st_2]

# Serialize sparse tensors to an array of byte strings
serialized_sparse_tensors = [tf.io.serialize_sparse(st).numpy() for st in sparse_tensors]

# Write to TFRecord
with tf.io.TFRecordWriter('sparse_example.tfrecord') as tfwriter:
    for sst in serialized_sparse_tensors:
        sparse_example = tf.train.Example(features = 
                     tf.train.Features(feature=
                         {'sparse_tensor': 
                               tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=sst))
                         }))
        # Append each example into tfrecord
        tfwriter.write(sparse_example.SerializeToString())

def parse_fn(data_element):
    features = {'sparse_tensor': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.string)}
    parsed = tf.io.parse_single_example(data_element, features=features)

    # tf.io.deserialize_many_sparse() requires the dimensions to be [N,3] so we add one dimension with expand_dims
    parsed['sparse_tensor'] = tf.expand_dims(parsed['sparse_tensor'], axis=0)
    # deserialize sparse tensor
    parsed['sparse_tensor'] = tf.io.deserialize_many_sparse(parsed['sparse_tensor'], dtype=tf.int32)
    # convert from sparse to dense
    parsed['sparse_tensor'] = tf.sparse.to_dense(parsed['sparse_tensor'])
    # remove extra dimenson [1, 3] -> [3]
    parsed['sparse_tensor'] = tf.squeeze(parsed['sparse_tensor'])
    return parsed

# Read from TFRecord
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(['sparse_example.tfrecord'])
dataset = dataset.map(parse_fn)
# Pad and batch dataset
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(2, padded_shapes={'sparse_tensor':[None,None]})

dataset.__iter__().get_next()
```

This outputs:

```py
{'sparse_tensor': <tf.Tensor: id=295, shape=(2, 4, 4), dtype=int32, numpy=
     array([[[1, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 2, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0]],

            [[0, 3, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [9, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 5]]], dtype=int32)>}
```

Comment: maybe add `axis=0` to tf.squeeze() to make sure only the expanded dimension to be removed?

Answer (score 2):

Since Tensorflow currently only supports 3 types in tfrecord: Float, Int64, and Bytes and a SparseTensor usually has more than 1 type, my solution is to convert the SparseTensor to Bytes with `Pickle`.

Here is a sample code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

#---------------------------------#
# Write to a tfrecord file

# create two sparse matrices (simulate the values from .eval() of SparseTensor)
a = csr_matrix(np.arange(12).reshape((4,3)))
b = csr_matrix(np.random.rand(20).reshape((5,4)))

# convert them to pickle bytes
p_a = pickle.dumps(a)
p_b = pickle.dumps(b)

# put the bytes in context_list and feature_list
## save p_a in context_lists 
context_lists = tf.train.Features(feature={
    'context_a': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[p_a]))
    })
## save p_b as a one element sequence in feature_lists
p_b_features = [tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[p_b]))]
feature_lists = tf.train.FeatureLists(feature_list={
    'features_b': tf.train.FeatureList(feature=p_b_features)
    })

# create the SequenceExample
SeqEx = tf.train.SequenceExample(
    context = context_lists,
    feature_lists = feature_lists
    )
SeqEx_serialized = SeqEx.SerializeToString()

# write to a tfrecord file
tf_FWN = 'test_pickle1.tfrecord'
tf_writer1 = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tf_FWN)
tf_writer1.write(SeqEx_serialized)
tf_writer1.close()

#---------------------------------#
# Read from the tfrecord file

# first, define the parse function
def _parse_SE_test_pickle1(in_example_proto):
    context_features = {
        'context_a': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string)
        }
    sequence_features = {
        'features_b': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([1], dtype=tf.string)
        }
    context, sequence = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(
      in_example_proto, 
      context_features=context_features,
      sequence_features=sequence_features
      )
    p_a_tf = context['context_a']
    p_b_tf = sequence['features_b']

    return tf.tuple([p_a_tf, p_b_tf])

# use the Dataset API to read
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tf_FWN)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_SE_test_pickle1)
dataset = dataset.batch(1)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(iterator.initializer)

[p_a_bat, p_b_bat] = sess.run(next_element)

# 1st index refers to batch, 2nd and 3rd indices refers to the sequence position (only for b)
rec_a = pickle.loads(p_a_bat[0])
rec_b = pickle.loads(p_b_bat[0][0][0])

# check whether the recovered the same as the original ones.
assert((rec_a - a).nnz == 0)
assert((rec_b - b).nnz == 0)

# print the contents
print("\n------ a -------")
print(a.todense())
print("\n------ rec_a -------")
print(rec_a.todense())
print("\n------ b -------")
print(b.todense())
print("\n------ rec_b -------")
print(rec_b.todense())
```

Here is what I got:

```
------ a -------
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]

------ rec_a -------
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]

------ b -------
[[ 0.88612402  0.51438017  0.20077887  0.20969243]
 [ 0.41762425  0.47394715  0.35596051  0.96074408]
 [ 0.35491739  0.0761953   0.86217511  0.45796474]
 [ 0.81253723  0.57032448  0.94959189  0.10139615]
 [ 0.92177499  0.83519464  0.96679833  0.41397829]]

------ rec_b -------
[[ 0.88612402  0.51438017  0.20077887  0.20969243]
 [ 0.41762425  0.47394715  0.35596051  0.96074408]
 [ 0.35491739  0.0761953   0.86217511  0.45796474]
 [ 0.81253723  0.57032448  0.94959189  0.10139615]
 [ 0.92177499  0.83519464  0.96679833  0.41397829]]
```